How to determine all symmetric bilinear and sesquilinear forms
Let $( T )$ be the rotation with matrix representation
$
T=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$
(a) Determine all symmetric bilinear forms $ \langle x, y\rangle $ on $\mathbb{R}^{2} $, such that for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $ it holds that $ \langle x, T x\rangle=0 $.
(b) Determine all sesquilinear forms $ \langle x, y\rangle $ on $ \mathbb{C}^{2} $, such that for all $ x \in \mathbb{C}^{2} $ it holds that $ \langle x, T x\rangle=0 $.
i'm not sure how to approach this and solve it, but i will share what i have done anyway :
A symmetric bilinear form can be represented by a symmetric matrix A as ⟨x,y⟩=$x^TAy$, where A is a symmetric matrix of the form
$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$
then the condition ⟨x,Tx⟩=0 translates to $x^TATx=0$
$
\langle x, T x\rangle = x^T A T x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -x_2 \\ x_1 \end{bmatrix}
$
$
= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -bx_2 + ax_1 \\ -cx_2 + bx_1 \end{bmatrix} = -bx_2x_1 + ax_1^2 - cx_2^2 + bx_1x_2
$
$
= ax_1^2 - cx_2^2
$
For this expression to be zero for all $ x_1, x_2 $, it must be that a=c=0
for b)
started same with $
x^* A Tx = 0
$
$ A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ \overline{b} & d \end{array}\right] $
then i will get
$
\left[\begin{array}{cc} \overline{x_1} & \overline{x_2} \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ \overline{b} & d \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c} -x_2 \\ x_1 \end{array}\right] = 0.
$
= $
- a \overline{x_1} x_2 - b \overline{x_1} x_1 + \overline{b} \overline{x_2} x_2 + d \overline{x_2} x_1 = 0.
$
=$ x^* (ATx) = -b |x_1|^2 + \overline{b} |x_2|^2 - a x_1^* x_2 + d x_2^* x_1 $
so then i said b should be equal to 0 and a and d equal to zero too since i said if a=-d
i will get 2Im and if a=d i will get 2Re, so it must be 0 to be their sum 0
PS: before answering please NO EIGENVALUES APPROACH, it's not allowed yet to be used
